# Changing ImageUrl onclick ImageButton Programmatically C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to change ImageUrl onclick Imagebutton that is present on my Repeater. I have to change it from behind code(cs file) not using jquery or js.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgLike" ImageUrl="Content/images/thumbsup.png" onclick="imgLike_Click" runat="server" style="width:25px;height:25px" />
```

and here is code

```
  protected void imgLike_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton imgLike = (ImageButton)rptinserting.FindControl("imgLike");
        imgLike.ImageUrl = "Content/images/thumbsup1.png";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cast the sender back to an ImageButton and change the `ImageUrl`.

```
protected void imgLike_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton imgLike = sender as ImageButton;
    imgLike.ImageUrl = "/Content/images/thumbsup1.png";
}
```

Comment: Wrap the databinding of the Repeater in an IsPostBack `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { //bind the data }`